# Submit button doesn't fire

Tags: php, forms, submit

My submit button suddenly stopped working. It submits data into a MySQL database.
While I was doing some design changes, it suddenly stopped working.

Are there any apparent errors/mistakes in the code below?
I'm a noob who's currently trying to learn some PHP and so on, so any help would be much appreciated. :)

```
<section id="moviesearch">
  <!-- Section -->
  <div class="subcribe2">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Container -->
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Row -->
        <div class="col-md-4">

        </div>

        <body ng-app="myApp">
          <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="col-md-4">
            <form class="form-watch-list-create">
              <input required="required" placeholder="Movie title" type="text" class="form-control" typeahead="item.Title for item in getLocation($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" typeahead-min-length="2" typeahead-wait-ms="1000" typeahead-on-select="onSelected($item)"
              typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html" ng-model="asyncSelected">
              <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
          </div>


          <div class="col-md-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-dark">Add to watchlist</button>
          </div>

        </body>
      </div>
      <!-- End Row -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Container -->
  </div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">
    <a>
      <span bind-html-unsafe="match.label | typeaheadHighlight:query" style="width: auto;"></span>
      ({{match.model.Year}})

      <!-- <img ng-src="{{match.model.Poster}}" width="120"> -->
    </a>
  </script>

  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Edit**
Here's the code that sends data into the MYSQL database:

```
function addWatchList() {
    if (isset($_GET['addtowatchlist'])) {
        $name = $_GET['name'];
        $conn = dbmysql();
        $query ="INSERT INTO watch_list values(null,'{$name}','{$_SESSION['user_id']}','NOW()')";
        if (mysqli_query($conn,$query)) {
            $last = "SELECT * FROM watch_list WHERE created_by  = '{$_SESSION['user_id']}' order by id desc limit 1";
            $data = mysqli_query($conn,$last);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
                include "_view.php";    
            }
        }else {
            echo "An error occurred. Please try again.";
        }
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: check your console and errors

Comment: there's no php here btw, so why the tag for it?

Comment: Sorry, that's my mistake. My head is a little busted from trying to fix this problem. There isn't anything happening in the console. The button just doesnt do anything

Answer (score 1):

I am looking to your code, missing attribute `action="somefile.php"` and  `method="get"` if you are planning on submitting it using the form, you should put it or if you are planning on submitting your code using javascript you can use `<form onsubmit="myFunction()">` That is what you are missing. I am not seeing you `addtowatchlist` name from your input so that php can catch it to your isset.

Answer (score 0):

The submit button isn't inside the form.

You're missing the `</form>` tag to end the `<form>`. But you have `</div>` that matches the `<div>` just before `</form>`, so it's implicitly closing the `<form>` tag as well. Then you have `<input type="submit">` after it. Since the submit button isn't inside the form, and has no `form` tag associating it with the form, it doesn't know which form it should submit when you click on it.

Try this:

```
<form class="form-watch-list-create">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="col-md-4">  
        <input 
            required="required"
            placeholder="Movie title"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            typeahead="item.Title for item in getLocation($viewValue)"
            typeahead-loading="loadingLocations"
            typeahead-min-length="2"
            typeahead-wait-ms="1000"
            typeahead-on-select="onSelected($item)"
            typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html"
            ng-model="asyncSelected">
        <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-dark">Add to watchlist</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This puts the form around both columns.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for the input.

Unfortunately, this did not do the trick. The submit button still doesnt work. No errors in the console or anything. :(

Comment: You have other problems with your HTML, like `<body>` inside `<section>` and `<div>`

Comment: There can only be one `<body>`, and it has to contain all the other HTML.

Comment: You're right. I have corrected it now, however these edits did not make the submit button work. I edited my first post with some more info.

Comment: Maybe there's also some AngularJS issues. I'm not very familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method attribute in form tag and end the form tag properly

```html
<form role="form" method="get" class="form-watch-list-create">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="col-md-4">  
        <input 
            required="required"
            placeholder="Movie title"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            typeahead="item.Title for item in getLocation($viewValue)"
            typeahead-loading="loadingLocations"
            typeahead-min-length="2"
            typeahead-wait-ms="1000"
            typeahead-on-select="onSelected($item)"
            typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html"
            ng-model="asyncSelected">
        <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-dark">Add to watchlist</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Waseem, I tried adding your suggestion, but the issue is the same. Nothing happens. I edited my first post with some more code

Comment: I see your edits, you can use method="get" in the form tag

Comment: Im not sure I understand. Why use method="get" for a post action?

Comment: because you have use $name = $_GET['name']; in your function.